# Daven mincha after lighting Shabbos candles

Tags: halacha, shabbat, candle-lighting, mincha-afternoon-prayer

As most shuls daven mincha right before Kaballos Shabbos, in order to daven mincha with a minyan on Friday one must light candles prior. Is it better to light candles and then daven mincha, or should one daven mincha alone and then light candles?

Comment: Tzvi, welcome to Mi Yodeya; thanks for bringing your question here! Please note that  this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends: use it as a jumping-off point for [a discussion with your rabbi](http://yodeya.com/q/9146). Also, please consider [registering](http://yodeya.com/users/login) your account for [access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) to more site features.

Comment: Can you indicate why you think the order of lighting/Mincha should matter?

Answer (score 2):

The conclusion of the Shulchan Aruch (263:10) is that you can light candles without accepting Shabbos through that lighting if you have that intention when lighting.  This intention does not need to be expressed (Rama there).  You should still make a beracha when lighting in this situation (Mishna Berura 263:42).  It would therefore be better to daven with a minyan if it is possible, and light before with intent to not accept Shabbos through the lighting.